# Generating a random number excluding 0 from an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, int

```
static ArrayList<Integer> usedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void arrayContents(){

usedArray.add(2, 2);
usedArray.add(1, 1);

}

public static void app(){

    Random generator = new Random ();

    int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(usedArray.size());

    System.out.println(usedArray);

    System.out.println(randomNumber);


    if(randomNumber == 2){
        score();
        question2();
        usedArray.remove(2);
        app();
    }
```

With

```
.add(2, 2)
```

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
```

However using

```
.add(2)
```

0 is generated as part of the array, even though it is not a value held within the array. Will arrays always contain 0 by default and is there any way of getting around this so that 0 cannot be generated as the random number ?

Comment: Please read the Class' javadoc before using it.

Comment: Why are you using the index based add at all? the .add(index, object) rather than just .add(object)

Comment: `ArrayLists` have *0-based* indexes(i.e)the starting index is `0` and the last index is `list.size()-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing this problem because when you create the arraylist it has zero size, when you then call `usedArray.add(2, 2);` you are trying to update the second place in your arraylist with Integer 2; but as I say, the arraylist currently has no number 2 slot. Unless you have a reason for using the `.add(index, object)` method just add them normally, as `.add(object)`

```
usedArray.add(2, 2); //<-- here you update slot 2, putting Integer 2 in it, there is no slot 2 at this point
```

If this is simply a list of available random numbers you can just use;

```
usedArray.add(1);
usedArray.add(2);
```

Now the numbers 1 and 2 are available in the arraylist.

These can then be fetched randomly from the arraylist:

```
int randomNumber = usedArray.get(generator.nextInt(usedArray.size()));
```

In this example `generator.nextInt(usedArray.size()` will produce the number 0 or 1, which will fetch 1 or 2 respectively from the arraylist

Comment: when 1 or 2 is removed from the arrayList, will only 0 be then generated as there is only 1 item in the arrayList?

Comment: @leo there is no zero in the arraylist unless you put one in there

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you create an empty `List` typing `new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

You can not use [add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) because its

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

for your list that has length equal to `0` an exception occur.

when you use `add(E e)` its.

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.

As Ted Hopp pointed out in comment

> The problem is that you cannot insert beyond the current end of the list.

This mean you can use `add(int index, E element)`, only if index is lover than size.

Additionally when you call

`int random = new Random().nextInt(list.size());`

Then result is between 0 (inclusive) and `list.size()` (exclusive). This mean that you will always result some valid index and you do not have to worry about the order.

Comment: So 0 is inclusive in the sense that it will always have a chance of being generated ?

Comment: List capacity has nothing to do with why OP is getting an exception. The problem is that you cannot insert beyond the current end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have removed 2nd position from list and trying to updating it. That's why your getting AIOBE. Use add() or try increase your list size.